# C# - MYSQL get specific rows column data

Tags: c#, mysql, database, row, vbulletin

So im developing this program that logs into a vbulletin website via mysql authentication, then i need to grab the logged in users subscription data. im not quite sure about how to do this and ive been stumbling over it for almost 2 days now.

i have the user table 'vbuser' which has all the user information. so if user 'xyz' logs in, i need to go to that row of the table, go the the column 'subscriptions', then read that to an array or datatable of sorts, then print each subscription to a listbox.

i have all the mysql connection and login code perfect, however ive been pouring how to do this task. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If user data is available on web site then you can use web scraping technique to fetch the data.

Comment: its not something that can be effectively scraped. the most efficient option is reading from the DB

Comment: @AaronFankhauser  Try this may it can help something http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/11/retrieving-data-from-a-mysql-database/

Comment: close but im still not able to populate a specific column from the selected users row and populate a datatable or listbox with that. thanks though.